# How can I build and test libffi under cygwin with mingw32?

Tags: cygwin, expect, autoconf, mingw32, libffi

After checking (most recent) tag v3.2.1:

```
% sh autogen.sh
% ./configure CC=i686-pc-mingw32-gcc
% make check
```

All tests appear to fail.

Using CC=gcc, tests seem to work properly.  Unfortunately I need the resulting build to have no cygwin dependencies, since I'm building a JNI DLL.

Comment: Probably :)  will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried building `libffi` using MSYS2 environment and `mingw-w64` and I hit the same wall:

**a)** all tests seem to fail when I run `make check`

**b)** when I try to compile the `libffi` *Hello World* example with `-lffi`,
   the linker complains about unresolved references to all ffi-related symbols (the symbols are indeed included in `libffi.a`, but probably due to circular dependencies and the order of object files, the linker fails to collect all the symbols)

**Fortunately**, if I drop `-lffi` and instead include all object files (`*.o`) created by libffi `make` operation, the created executable runs just fine.

Here's a link to the libffi *Hello World* example I used:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/libffi-dev/html/Closure-Example.html

**[EDIT]**

After some additional experiments, I managed to compile the program by replacing `-lffi` with **`-Wl,--whole-archive,-lffi,--no-whole-archive`**. This way, the linker would include all object files from `libffi.a` and everything would work just fine.

Here's the *Hello World* example (**`hello.c`**) with detailed steps I used, in case someone finds this info useful:

```
/*
 * Steps for building libffi on Windows and running this Hello World example:
 *
 * 1. Download and install the latest version of MSYS2
 *    a) download the latest (64-bit or 32-bit) installer from http://msys2.github.io
 *    b) run the installer accepting default settings
 *    c) execute the following commands to update the system core
 *        pacman -Sy pacman
 *        pacman -Syu
 *        pacman -Su
 *    d) restart MSYS2, if requested to do so
 *    e) execute the following command to install development tools
 *       for 64-bit gcc:
 *        pacman --needed -S base-devel dejagnu mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
 *       for 32-bit gcc:
 *        pacman --needed -S base-devel dejagnu mingw-w64-i686-gcc
 *    f) restart MSYS2
 * 2. Download and compile the latest version of libffi
 *    a) download the latest source code bundle from https://github.com/libffi/libffi/releases
 *    b) unpack the source code bundle in MSYS2 tmp directory (e.g. C:\msys64\tmp)
 *    c) execute the following MSYS2 commands to compile libffi (adapt the version number):
 *        cd /tmp/libffi-3.2.1
 *        ./autogen.sh
 *        ./configure --prefix=/tmp/out --enable-static --disable-shared
 *        make
 *    d) optionally, execute the following command to run the tests:
 *        make check
 *    e) copy the distributable files to the configured /tmp/out directory
 *        make install
 *       the following files are needed for the next step:
 *        /tmp/out/lib/libffi.a
 *        /tmp/out/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include/ffi.h
 *        /tmp/out/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include/ffitarget.h
 * 3. Compile this example
 *    a) copy this file to MSYS2 tmp directory (e.g. C:\msys64\tmp\hello.c)
 *    b) execute the following MSYS2 command to compile the example:
 *        gcc -I /tmp/out/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -L /tmp/out/lib -lffi -o /tmp/hello /tmp/hello.c
 *    c) run the example (/tmp/hello.exe), the output should be:
 *        Hello World!
 *
 * Troubleshooting
 *
 * If the tests seem to fail and the compilation in step 3b) above reports undefined references to 'ffi_*' symbols,
 * try compiling using the following command instead:
 *        gcc -I /tmp/out/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -L /tmp/out/lib -Wl,--whole-archive,-lffi,--no-whole-archive -o /tmp/hello /tmp/hello.c
 * Another alternative is to try linking the original libffi object files (*.o) and drop -lffi as follows:
 * For 64-bit version:
 *        export SRC=/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/src
 *        gcc -I /tmp/out/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -o /tmp/hello /tmp/hello.c $SRC/prep_cif.o $SRC/types.o $SRC/raw_api.o $SRC/java_raw_api.o $SRC/closures.o $SRC/x86/ffi.o $SRC/x86/win64.o
 * For 32-bit version:
 *        export SRC=/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/i686-w64-mingw32/src
 *        gcc -I /tmp/out/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -o /tmp/hello /tmp/hello.c $SRC/prep_cif.o $SRC/types.o $SRC/raw_api.o $SRC/java_raw_api.o $SRC/closures.o $SRC/x86/ffi.o $SRC/x86/win32.o
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ffi.h>

/* Acts like puts with the file given at time of enclosure */
void puts_binding(ffi_cif* cif, void* ret, void* args[], void* stream) {
  *(ffi_arg*) ret = fputs(*(char**) args[0], (FILE*) stream);
}

typedef int (*puts_t)(char*);

int main() {
  ffi_cif cif; /* The call interface */
  ffi_type* args[1]; /* The array of pointers to function argument types */
  ffi_closure* closure; /* The allocated closure writable address */
  void* bound_puts; /* The allocated closure executable address */
  int rc; /* The function invocation return code */

  /* Allocate closure (writable address) and bound_puts (executable address) */
  closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof(ffi_closure), &bound_puts);

  if (closure) {
    /* Initialize the array of pointers to function argument types */
    args[0] = &ffi_type_pointer;

    /* Initialize the call interface describing the function prototype */
    if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 1, &ffi_type_sint, args) == FFI_OK) {
      /* Initialize the closure, setting stream to stdout */
      if (ffi_prep_closure_loc(closure, &cif, puts_binding, stdout, bound_puts) == FFI_OK) {
        rc = ((puts_t) bound_puts)("Hello World!");
        /* rc now holds the result of the call to fputs */
      }
    }
  }

  /* Deallocate both closure, and bound_puts */
  ffi_closure_free(closure);

  return 0;
}
```